# Override Django ModelForm's Clean_unique method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a django app where i have a model which have a field with attribute unique=True. I am trying to save data in this model using ModelForm. My model and Model form is like this.

My models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field1


class DuplicateFields(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean_field1(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['field1']
        if value :
            if MyModel.objects.filter(field1=value).count() > 0:
                DuplicateFields.objects.create(field1=value)
            return Value
        raise forms.ValidationError('this field is required')

    **I tried below given code  also but it also raise Unique field Exception or error **

    def clean_unique(form, field, exclude_initial=True, 
        value = form.cleaned_data.get(field)
        if value:
            objs = MyModel.objects.filter(field1=value)
            if objs.count() > 0:
                DuplicateFields.objects.create(field1=value)   
        return value
    def clean_field1(self):
        value=clean_unique(self,'field1')
```

**My Views.py is **

```
if request.method=='POST':
      form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
          field = cleaned_data['field1']
          form.save()
          return HttpResponse('form has been saved successfully')
      else:
          print 'form is invalid'
          print form._errors
          return render_to_response(template_name, {'form':form}, ci)            
else:   
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'form':form}, ci)
```

What i want to do is while saving the data or calling `form.is_valid()` method if i found that the data i am trying to store already exists in model then instead of raising a validation error i want to perform some other logic like will store it in some other model.

But in my view when i am calling 'form.is_valid()` it is returning False. Give me some suggestions. Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop giving validate unique modelform exception what you can do is just override the django ModelForm's validate_unique method. like

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def validate_unique(self):
    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
    try:
        self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
    except forms.ValidationError as e:
        try:
            del e.error_dict['field1']  #if field1 unique validation occurs it will be omitted and form.is_valid() method pass
        except:
            pass
        self._update_errors(e) #if there are other errors in the form those will be returned to views and is_valid() method will fail.
```

and in your view check

```
 if form.is_valid():
    field1=form.cleaned_data['form1']
    try:
        MyModel.objects.get(field1=field1)
        #write your logic here for duplicate entry
    except:
         MyModel.objects.create(field1=field1)
    return render_to_response('template.html')
 else:
    return render_to_response('template.html')
```

Comment: Yes, i was looking for the same, Thanks